# Want to open a modal pop up from a link to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have wrote a javascript function containing student id, student name and details. What I want to do is to open a pop up window when a link from a student in a students' list is clicked. I want the pop up window will be in another page. I just want to pass student id, name to that page.

```
function opentestimonial(st_Id,stName,details){
                    window.localStorage.setItem("st_Id", JSON.stringify(st_Id));
                    document.getElementById("openmodal").innerHTML= localStorage.getItem("st_Id");
                    window.open("testimonial1.html","socialPopupWindow","location=no, width=500, height=600");
                }
```

Function call

Testimonials

Comment: share your code please

Comment: Is that other page is already opened ? or you want to open a window with the popup ?

Comment: the second one is correct

Comment: gib codde ples mohona

Answer (score 0):

just pass id in query string, and on document load you can call your popup and use id from url ( querystring )